# adding popup function to existing jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having difficulties with a jQuery plugin (cookieguard). I'm trying to add a pop-up function to one of the links (when clicking on 'More information', cookies.html should open in a new window), however it doesn't seem to work. I am trying to implement this code into the plugin:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="window.open('
                cookies.html ', '
                cookiepopup ', '
                width = 600, height = 500 '); return false;">More information</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J3gP8/

Any ideas why this doesn't work? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is caused due to the single quotes not escaped properly. Please update the code as shown below.

```
a(".cookie-guard-msg-inner").addClass("onlyEssential").append('<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="window.open(\'cookies.html\', \'cookiepopup\',\'width = 600, height = 500 \'); return false;">More information</a><a href="#" class="cookie-guard-okay">Accept</a>');
```

Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/J3gP8/2/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you didn't escaped single quotes in the code you append in the plugin code.
please update to escape the single quotes and it will work fine.

Please see here: 
`fiddle`[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UD3Ct/4/)